# Wait for multiple non nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, coding-style

Say I have two (or more) asynchronous operations `op1` and `op2` that call a callback function upon completion. How do I best wait for both to complete before starting `op3`?
I am **not** able to nest them inside of each other (i.e. first starting `op1`, then starting `op2` inside of `op1callback()`)
(I of course also do not know which of these is going to complete first, but that doesn't really matter I guess)

```
function op1callback {
}
function op2callback {
}
function op3 {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to just keep flags about the callbacks state:

```
let count = 0;

function callback() {
  if(++count === 2) op3();
}

op1(callback); op2(callback);
```

But in the long term it might be beneficial to let the operations return promises, e.g.:

```
 async function op1() { 
   // Do some async stuff and *await* that
   return "something";
 }
```

then you could just do:

```
 Promise.all(op1(), op2()).then(op3);
```